# How write write text line with thread c++

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli

I have program that creates text file and writes some random symbols. How to make that threads be writing those symbols? Here my code below:

```
static void MyThreadProc(){}
static const char alphanum[] = "0123456789";//this is random symbols I'm using
int stringLength = sizeof(alphanum) - 1;

char genRandom()   {
return alphanum[rand() % stringLength];
}

int main() {
String^ fileName = "file.txt";

StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);

srand(time(0));

Thread^ myThread1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
Thread^ myThread2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
//Here I create my threds

for (int z = 0; z < 21; z++){//This cycle writes 21 random simbol

// myThread1->sw->WriteLine(genRandom());   
// myThread1->sw->WriteLine(genRandom()); this threads I want to start writing symbols
    sw->WriteLine(genRandom()); //write random symbols
}
sw->Close();
}
```

Comment: First of all, this is not C++, it's C++-cli. The functionality for a thread, should be written in a Thread procedure (ThreadProc), which, you have, currently, defined as a no-op.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code uses threads to write symbols into text file:

```
public ref class Simple{
public:
static void Main(){

    String^ fileName = "file.txt";
    StreamWriter^ sw = gcnew StreamWriter(fileName);
    srand(time(0));
    Thread^ myTread1 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
    myTread1->Start();
    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++){
        sw->WriteLine(genRandom());
    }
    myTread1->Join();
    Thread^ myTread2 = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(MyThreadProc));
    myTread2->Start();

    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++){
        sw->WriteLine(genRandom());
    }
    myTread2->Join();
    sw->Close();
}};
```